# How to I make this not pull up so many tabs at once?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, select, popup

So, I just want the website to pull up what is in the select in one line, which works, but also pops up 2 extra tabs :(. Any suggestions? I have been working really hard on this, I would hate ti see it go :(

```
var options = [];
var urls = [];

function addOption(name, url) {


  var select = document.getElementById('optionlist');
  var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
  var optionText = document.createTextNode(name);

  option.appendChild(optionText);
  select.appendChild(option);

  if (options.length > 0) {
    options.push(name);
    urls.push(url)
  } else {
    options = [name];
    urls = [url];
  }


}


function createOptions() {
  addOption("List of Gemstones", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minerals");
  addOption("Another Website", "https://www.google.com");
}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
  var select = document.getElementById('optionlist').value;

  for (a = 0; a <= options.length; a++) {
    var selected = options[a];

    if (selected == selected) {
      var toredirect = urls[a];
      var win = window.open(toredirect, '_blank');
      win.focus();
    } else if (selected === selected) {
      var toredirect = urls[a];
      var win = window.open(toredirect, '_blank');
      win.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add a Code Snippet please?

Comment: All the options in optionlist are populated from js or by default they are populated on page?

Comment: `if (selected == selected)` will always be true.

Comment: Did you mean to write `if (selected = select)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (selected == selected)` is always true, since you're just comparing a value with itself (an exception is if it contains `NaN`, but that's not relevant here). So every iteration of the loop will execute the `window.open()` code.

I think you meant to write `if (selected == select)`. But there's no need to loop to find the selected option, its index is in `document.getElementById('optionlist').selectedIndex`. So you can simply do:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    var index = document.getElementById('optionlist').selectedIndex;
    var toredirect = urls[index];
    var win = window.open(toredirect, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Also, in your `addOption()` function, you don't need to check the length of `options`. There's nothing wrong with calling `push()` on an empty array.